# use NSDateFormatter to parse Twitter strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, twitter

I'm trying to create a NSDate from a string returned by the twitter API
As I spent hours on this issue I created a sample app

```
NSString *testDate = @"Mon Jul 25 21:20:58 +0000 2011";
NSDateFormatter *frm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[frm setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterLongStyle];
[frm setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
[frm setDateFormat: @"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'Z' yyyy"];
NSDate *newDate = [frm dateFromString:testDate];
NSLog(@"newDate:%@", newDate);
```

To me this code 'should' work.

all I got is this :

```
2011-07-25 19:36:08.467 test[92:707] Test
2011-07-25 19:36:08.475 test[92:707] newDate:(null)
```

[I found this but it's not working either](http://davidjhinson.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/nsdateformatter-and-twitter/).

I have Lion + Xcode 4.1
My iPad is under 4.3.5

Thanks in advance for any help ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't kick yourself too hard...

In your format string, remove the apostrophes from around `Z`.  The apostrophes mean that it's going to be a literal `Z`, not the timezone.  If you remove those, it'll work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what worked for me

no quotes around Z like said Dave DeLong.
I used setLocale on the NSDateFormatter, it made it work better.

```
NSDateFormatter *frm = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[frm setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
[frm setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"];
```

Comment: Without setting the @"en_US_POSIX" locale identifier, the code snippet only worked on the simulator. Now it works on the device as well. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone finding this via Google, Twitter has apparently changed their date formats, at least for their `http://search.twitter.com/search.json` endpoint.

```
NSDate __attribute__((pure)) *parseTwitterDate(NSString *twitterDate) {
    NSDateFormatter *twitterDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.new;
    [twitterDateFormatter setDateFormat: @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
    return [twitterDateFormatter dateFromString:twitterDate];
};
```

Comment: Twitter search endpoint had since the beginning a different date format and I use the same solution as yours. Thanks for the catch, I should have been more precise with the question.

Comment: Interesting. That's the mark of a poorly designed API, that they can't even use a consistent (if obscure) date format throughout their API. They should just use ISO8601. </rant>